# Ajax call: Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'itemTypes'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, webmethod

I have created an ajax call and am trying to send an object as an argument to the server but I am getting the following error:

`Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'itemTypes'`

I have checked the itemTypes variable in javascript and it contains the expected values:

`sessionStorage.itemTypeUid = "18"`

`sessionStorage.itemTypeName = "TABLE_NAME"`

`args = {CurId: 18, BaseTableName: "TABLE_NAME"}`

**javascript:**

```
var itemTypes = {
            CurId: parseInt(sessionStorage.itemTypeUid),
            BaseTableName: sessionStorage.itemTypeName
        };

        aj("DeleteItem", itemTypes);
```

**Ajax:**

```
function aj(funcName, args) {
    retval = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'ItemEdit.asmx/' + funcName,
        data: JSON.stringify(args),
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            var errors = a + b + c
        }
    });
}
```

**VB:**

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Sub DeleteItem(itemTypes As Object)
    
            Dim CurId = ""
            Dim BaseTableName = ""
    
            actions.DeleteItem(CurId, BaseTableName)
        End Sub
```

Comment: What is `sessionStorage` variable here?

Comment: sessionStorage.itemTypeUid = "18", sessionStorage.itemTypeName = "GRIT_SALT_BINS", args = {CurId: 18, BaseTableName: "GRIT_SALT_BINS"}

Comment: So, `sessionStorage` is an object here?

Comment: @palaѕн Sorry, that didn't answer your question. Yes Session storage is an object with a bunch of values

Comment: Try to update your web method like `Public Sub DeleteItem(CurId As Integer, BaseTableName As String)`.. see if you are getting these values properly now.

Comment: Also, remove `Dim CurId = ""
            Dim BaseTableName = ""` from the method, so that there is no name conflicts.

Comment: I had tried that originally. Just tried again and getting "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'CurID'." EDIT: (just saw your second message, let me do that)

Comment: No... still the same error unfortunately

Comment: Try to pass data to ajax once like : `data: "{ CurId: '" + sessionStorage.itemTypeUid + "', BaseTableName: '" + sessionStorage.itemTypeName + "'}",` instead of  `data: JSON.stringify(args),`

Comment: Same error, and I made sure to parse itemTypeUid so that it gives 18 instead of "18"

Comment: Not sure what's happening on your end. I have done lots of these ajax calls with VB in past. It worked fine.

Comment: It's working now. I hadn't noticed the sub said CurID instead of CurId, so your solution did work, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The first one you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your web method like:

```vb
<WebMethod()>
Public Sub DeleteItem(CurId As Integer, BaseTableName As String)
   actions.DeleteItem(CurId, BaseTableName)
End Sub
```

Please make sure parameter name here is exactly the same as the values passed in the ajax call. Even if the name is the same but the casing is different, then you might get errors. So, please double-check the variable names first. Also, remove

```
Dim CurId = "" 
Dim BaseTableName = ""
```

from the method, so that there are no name conflicts.